# I'm wondering about how to make this table cell

Tags: html, html-table, cell

I'm trying to create this table:

[image]

Earlier, I did this below:

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td, th { border: solid #777 1px; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">title1</th>
    <th colspan="7" style="text-align: center;">grade</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="text-align: center;">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">title_1</td>
    <td>sub_1</td>
    <td>sub_2</td>
    <td>sub_3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I cannot make the title_1 / sub_1 line, sub_2 line, sub_3 line, or the num and 1111 cells. How can I do this?

Comment: so you want to create a table as shown in the image using html?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I understand your question, but If you are looking for a **html table** shown in your image here is the reference.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">title1</th>
        <th colspan="7">grade</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">title_1</td>
        <th>sub_1</th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>sub_2</th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>sub_3</th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">num</th>
        <td colspan="7">111</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```